# Magento 1.7 Correct the US spelling of cheque on invoice

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, invoice-pdf

I need to correct the US spelling of check to the correct English spelling 'cheque' on the invoice generated by Magento.

Ive changed the payment method name and it all looks ok within the Magento admin area but when you go to print the invoice or order it adds an extra line saying '**Send Check to:**' directly under the correct line **'Make Cheque payable to:'**
[image]

Where can I change this?

Ive checked through all the local files but cant find any reference to it. I am also using the pdfcustomiser by fooman but again Ive looked through those files and there is no reference to the word 'check'

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Is it showing same in admin or only on Invoice pdf? Can you mention if you are seeing the same in admin invoice, invoice email, order etc

Comment: its only showing on the pdf, in both the invoice and order section it is written correctly. It appears like this:Cheque / Invoice

Make Cheque payable to: 
Send Cheque to:
Accounts Payable

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who has this issue I found where the wrong spelling was coming from.

in:
**app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/payment/info/pdf/checkmo.phtml**

on line 37

There was a reference to a local file that wasnt working for some reason:

'__('Send Check to:') ?>'

I just changed this to a regular echo statement instead (it would probably be better to figure out why the info wasnt getting pulled by the local file but for my needs just replacing this line would be fine) I also copied the file into my theme rather than overwriting the default file.

Hope that helps someone